# CSS: text on button slightly off center

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a landing page and have a button where the text should be centered, but it's coming up slightly above the center.

```css
.button {
  background-color: #ED5E93;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 16px 0 16px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" className={indexStyles.button}>
       Get Started
    </button>
```

Comment: I can't seem to replicate this issue; https://codepen.io/Nerdpuff/pen/yLYRNze

Comment: Your example isn't plain HTML/CSS. E.g. `className={indexStyles.button}`

Answer (score 3):

Use flex CSS property

```css
button {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    background-color: #ED5E93;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 2rem;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 0 16px 0 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" className={indexStyles.button}>
   Get Started
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

using flex is what I usually use for things like this and it works really well.

Here is a link to the complete guide 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

As for your problem. This should work:

```
.button {
    background-color: #ED5E93;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 2rem;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 0 16px 0 16px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 3rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: Answer is the font itself. It had a lot of whitespace under it (Khula) that couldn't be removed. The code above works with a font that has equal whitespace above and below.

Comment: But what if you want to use that font? Can you adjust the base line somehow?